# Retry failed requests with useFetch composable in NUXT 3

Tags: javascript, fetch, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to use usefetch for making API calls in NUXT 3 app. I've 2 additional requirements:

1. Add Authorization header with each request - I've got a solution to this by defining custom composable as suggested in [here](https://github.com/enkot/nuxt/blob/c332259a2342ea0d154b6421f6de7ca881730f97/examples/other/use-custom-fetch-composable/composables/useCustomFetch.ts)
2. In case the token is expired, fetch the latest token and retry the same request - I've not found any answer for this requirement. Can anyone please suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing this problem. Didn't know how to evaluate. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use OnResponseError for fetch new token and send the request again, because the method is Promise type and not return data. but you can use this way to setup refresh token and send request and return the data.

```
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'
import { defu } from 'defu'

export async function useCustomFetch<T> (url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  const userAuth = useCookie('token')
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()

  const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
    baseURL: config.baseUrl ?? 'https://api.nuxtjs.dev',
    // cache request
    key: url,

    // set user token if connected
    headers: userAuth.value
      ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${userAuth.value}` }
      : {}
  }

  // for nice deep defaults, please use unjs/defu
  const params = defu(defaults, options)

  let result = await useFetch(url, params)

  if (result.error.statusCode === 401) {
    const { token } = await fetchNewToken()

    userAuth.value = token

    result = await useFetch(url, { ...params, header: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
  }

  return result
}
```